# How to store value from loop in liquid to display it into the variable

Tags: loops, shopify, liquid

I am solving here issue - If the customer comes via direct url to the product, I don't get the collection name in the form(because it's not contained in the url). How can I solve this please, so that the collection listed by foor loop gets into a variable and can be displayed at the bottom.

I am trying to display the result of the loop into a variable.
[image: Here is my code]

the collection.title is still blank in this case because when the for cycle ends it will lost all the data.

Any solution please?

I tried to assign the result of the for loop to a variable, but it failed. I had syntax problems. I thought of assigning a collection with index [1] here. Since the index [0] contains the generic name of the collection, I need to use [1] - technically I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
{% assign myTitle = '' %}
{% for collection in product.collections reversed offset:1 %}
   {% assign myTitle = collection.title %}
   {% break %}
{% endfor %}

{{ myTitle }}
```

Obviously, it would be a good idea to add some if statements around the assignment to make sure the correct title gets assigned and later on if myTitle is not empty but at minimum, this should do the trick. Remember that this code is going to work well if the product has only one collection but this assumption usually is wrong.

EDIT: optionally you can add a break statement like I did to break it after the first iteration so it won't get reassigned. With this code we assume that the correct title is the title of the first collection in the loop (which could not be true)